# fields with class constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I have a  class that has a generic type  with a type constraint of class

the definition looks like this

```
public class ConnectedRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
```

I then use this in the following method:

```
 public void LoadData<T>() where T:class
        {
             var GenRep = new ConnectedRepository<T>(c);
            grdData.DataSource = GenRep.ToBindingList();
        }
```

my problem is that i need to use GenRep elsewhere in the class that contains this method and so I need to define it outside this method but i cannot find the right syntax for this

I need something like:

```
ConnectedRepository<??> GenRep;
```

but cant figure out the correct type definition

Any help would be much appreciated

```
Code for my repository:
 public class ConnectedRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal DbContext _context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

        public ConnectedRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> ToBindingList()
        {
            _dbSet.Load();
            return _dbSet.Local.ToBindingList();
        }
        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

this is to be used from a user control that contains a gridview

```
public partial class DataView : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl 
{
    TechnicalServicesContext c = new TechnicalServicesContext();


   /// <summary>
   /// 
   /// </summary>
    public DataView() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public void LoadData<T>() where T:class
    {
         var GenRep = new ConnectedRepository<T>(c);
        grdData.DataSource = GenRep.ToBindingList();

    }
   public void SaveData()
    {

    }


}
```

This is a re-usable display that I want to  use for any entity

Comment: Replace `??` with the actual type name? You can't use the type argument outside of a generic method. Maybe you want to make your entire class generic instead.

Comment: Can you clarify something. `ConnectedRepository` is a `class`, and `LoadData` is an instance method. Is `LoadData` an instance method in `ConnectedRepository`, or in another `class`? And `GenRep` is a member field/property of which class?

Comment: Hi , sorry for not being clearer. The connectedRepository is a repository for my entity objects in my dbcontext, (i.e domain classes). the variable C is my context. I'm trying to create a generic repository than can perform crud on any of my entities - this is all good but when i come to call these operatiosn from a datagrid view on a user control that's where i run into this problem

Comment: I've added some more code to make it clearer

Comment: Create a common interface with the common functionality across any `T`, and then declare the field to hold that interface, then implement the interface on that type. You can't pick a `T` that will fix "can hold any `ConnectedRepository<T>`"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's perfectly clear what you want. If I got it right that you want to use the same instance of the generic type ConnectedRepository, with the same underlying type, in more than one place within an object of the surrounding class, then I'd say you'd need to make the class dependant on that , instead of just a single method of the class.

```
public class ConnectedRepository<TEntity,T>
   where TEntity : class
   where T:class
{
    ConnectedRepository<T> GenRep;

    public ConnectedRepository(int c)
    {
        GenRep = new ConnectedRepository<T>(c); // now sure what c is, bt you could pass it to the constructor like this, if GenRep needs it
    }

     public void LoadData()
     {
        grdData.DataSource = GenRep.ToBindingList();
     }

     public void DoStuff()
     {  // do something else with  GenRep ?
     }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I've added some code to hopefuflly make things a bit clearer The calling class is from a user control that i want to use to display any data from any entity, hense why I was trying to make the repository generic.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create new instance for your repository for each new type of data. It will consume a lot memory for a lot of different data types.
You could use static class wrapper with generic methods

```
 public static class ConnectedRepository
    {
        private static DbContext _context;


        public static SetContext(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

        } 

     public static IEnumerable<TEntity> ToBindingList<TEntity>() :  where TEntity : class
            {
                var dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
                dbSet.Load()
                return dbSet.Local.ToBindingList();
            }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip -  that's a cleaner solution and will fit's with what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Store it as a private within the class like

```
private ConnectedRepository<T> _genRep;
```

Looking at this further, are you saying that you want a generic function of type T, where T is not mentioned within the class header?? That's not allowed. All the types that a generic class operates on must be declared in its header, and substitution happens at compile time.